# xslt passing position as a parameter is producing strange results?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, position

I have an xml file which looks like this:

```
<section>
  <title> title of section </title>
  <table>
     <title> title of table</title>
     <tableData columns = 2>
     <column width ="50"/>
     <column width ="100"/>
     <tableHead>
        <row>
             <entry>column 1</entry>
        </row> 
        <row>
             <entry>column 2</entry>
        </row>
     </tableHead>
     <tableBody>
       <row>
             <entry>text</entry>
             <entry>abc</entry>
       </row> 
       <row>
             <entry>text</entry>
             <entry>dbe</entry>
      </row> 
       <row>
             <entry>text</entry>
             <entry>fgh</entry>
       </row> 
     </tableBody>
   </table>
 </section>
```

I need to process each entry in tableHead/row/entry and spit it out in some format that also includes the columnWidth. So, my output must look like 
{"name":"column 1", "width":"50px"},{"name":"column 2", "width":"100px"}

My transform looks like this

```
 <xsl:template match="//table/tableHead/row/entry">
    <xsl:text>{"name": "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select"."/>
    <xsl:text>", "width":"</xsl:text>

    <xsl:call-template name="get_column_width">
       <xsl:with-param name ="rowNum">
          <xsl:value-of sellect"position()"/>
       </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template name ="get_column_width">
     <xsl:param-name="rowNum">
     <xsl:value-of select="../../../columnWidth[$rowNum]/@width"/>
     <xsl:text>px"}</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
```

Strangely, this produces {"name":"column 1", "width":"50 100px"},{"name":"column 2", "width":"50 100px"}

However, when I output only the rowNum parameter I get exactly what I expect:

{"name":"column 1", "width":1px"},{"name":"column 2", "width":"2px"}

So, rowNum is 1 and 2 so the select statement will use columnWidth[1] and columnWidth[2], but for whatever reason it just outputs both of them. I tried using columnWidth[1] in the select and it outputs 50 as I would expect. columnWidth[2] outputs 100. I'm really confused here. Using preceding-sibling gave the same result. Is there something wrong with my template matching?

Unfortunately changing the xml format is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../columnWidth[$rowNum]/@width"/>
```

**Use**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../columnWidth[position() = $rowNum]/@width"/>
```

**Explanation**

In XPath:

```
someExpression[someInteger]
```

is a shorthand for:

```
someExpression[position() = someInteger]
```

However, in case of:

```
someExpression[$someVariableReference]
```

the XPath 1.0 processor typically doesn't know what value and of what type is contained in the variable. Therefore, it converts this variable to a boolean value (`true()` or `false()`) to perform the complete evaluation.

By definition:

```
boolean(someNumber)
```

is equivalent to:

```
not(somenumber = 0)
```

As neither of the numbers 1 and 2 is zero, the predicate `[$rowNum]` is `true()` in both cases,

Thus:

```
../../../columnWidth[$rowNum]/@width
```

selects the `width` attributes of both `columnWidth` elements.

Comment: Even better, follow the advice which I give over and over again: don't use `<xsl:var><xsl:value-of select="X"/></xsl:var>` when you could use `<xsl:var select="X"/>`. You want the variable to be an integer, not a result tree fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The value of $rowNum is a result tree fragment (or in XSLT 2.0, a document node). The effective boolean value of a result tree fragment (or a node) is always true. You probably imagined that the value was an integer. But to set a variable to an integer, you should write

```
<xsl:with-param name="x" select="position()"/>
```

not

```
<xsl:with-param name="x">
  <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
</xsl:with-param>
```

Sadly the latter construct seems to be incredibly prevalent, considering how verbose and inefficient it is, and how occasionally (as here) it gives the wrong answer.